# "This site can't be reached." error when connecting to pgadmin4 docker image hosted in Debian VM in GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, pgadmin-4

pgadmin4 is a docker image running inside a Debian VM hosted in Google Cloud. I have already enabled http and https traffic for it. I ran the docker image using the following command:

```
root@fastapi-celery:~# docker run -p 5050:80 \
    -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com" \
    -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin" \
    -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

This is the logs for it during initialization:

```
pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================**

[2023-01-25 09:23:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-01-25 09:23:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
[2023-01-25 09:23:20 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2023-01-25 09:23:20 +0000] [90] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 90
```

This is my netstat command result:

```
root@fastapi-celery:\~# sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5556            0.0.0.0:\*       LISTEN      180176/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:\*       LISTEN      497/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5050            0.0.0.0:\*       LISTEN      262783/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:\*       LISTEN      182361/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::5556                 :::\*            LISTEN      180182/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::\*            LISTEN      497/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::5050                 :::\*            LISTEN      262789/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::\*            LISTEN      182366/docker-proxy
```

I have tried stopping and restarting the docker image but it obviously didn't work. I am really not sure how to      proceed debugging this.

Comment: You're exposing pgadmin on port 5050, have you opened that up in the VM:s firewall? HTTP and HTTPS usually only opens ports 80 and 443, respectively.

Comment: thanks M.O. I solved the problem by adding the port to the firewall rules in GCP. I checked the VM per your comment and it was working when I did a curl command. Thus GCP was the culprit.